# Making result of division a float with 2 decimal places (Python)

Tags: python, division

I know this is a noob question but, is it possible to make the result of a division a float with 2 decimal places?

For example when dividing 50 by 2 the result is 25.0. When divided by 3 the result is 16.666666666666668. Can I force both results to be a float with 2 decimal places?

Thanks, and sorry!

Comment: I think you are confused about the difference between numbers and their visual representation ...

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> round(16.666666666666668,2)
16.67
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like:

```
x = 16.666666666
rounded_x = format(x, '.2f') #This will be a string
```